# Workstations' records not updating in DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp

I have a firewall appliance that uses DNS records of PCs and user authentication from LDAP.
(Windows environment).
The PCs in the environment are displaying old DNS records and not updating.
This in turn is affecting the firewall (due to multiple computers having the same DNS record).
It isnt happening to all workstations. Majority are updating but some just wont.
Any ideas?
DHCP is providing the addresses no problems but from there the new records dont seem to be getting to DNS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the permissions on the DNS entry directory objects in the DomainDNSZones/ForestDNSZones container.

I've seen situations where the permissions don't allow the workstation to update its own address due to permissions issues, specifically a DHCP server creating DNS entries on behalf of clients that have restrictive permissions (but static entries created by a user would do the same).

Are the offending entries static?  If they aren't.. do you have scavenging enabled?

And, stating the obvious, but: make sure the "Register this connection's address in DNS" box is checked on the NIC (IPv4 -> Advanced).

Comment: Where are the permissions applied to this container. I see the container in DNS but no security options. Thanks for the quick post

Comment: You'll actually want to look at the permissions on the individual entries, as that's any permission problems would reside.  ADSIEdit is probably the best way to get a look at the real structure of the AD-integrated DNS and the security settings for the objects.

Comment: ok cheers, scavenging is enabled. Entried are not static. All DHCP

Comment: I found that there was a broken sid in the records that were not updating. When I deleted the record and performed a registerdns on the client the broken sid was replaced by the computername$ which had full control. This must have been the permission that was the issue.